# Python Selenium _ Error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm studying how Selenium works.
There are some elements that are fully loaded, but can't be clickable.
Here's the example of the case.
Selenium took a time until it is fully loaded. Still the button is not clickable. I think Selenium can't find the element. How can I resolve this issue?

**url**

```
https://www.google.co.kr/
```

**button that I'm trying to click**

```
<a class="gb_A" aria-label="Google 앱" href="https://www.google.co.kr/intl/ko/about/products" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0"><svg class="gb_Se" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M6,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM6,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM12,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM16,6c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2s2,-0.9 2,-2 -0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2zM12,8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,20c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2z"></path></svg></a>
```

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr/")
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gbwa']/div/a/svg/path"))).click()
```

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\selenium test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gbwa']/div/a/svg/path"))).click()
  File "C:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Try using //a[@class='gb_A']//*[local-name()='path'] or //a[@class='gb_A']/*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='path']

Comment: It works now. I made a mistake with the ID locating. Thank you so much !!

Comment: No problem have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,20)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='gb_A']/*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='path']"))).click()
```

Seemed to work now just putting this to complete the question. Was an issue with xpath identification.